# What Can Cause a Linq to SQL Object to Ignore New Values?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, or maybe something sinister is happening, but this seems strange to me.  I have a Linq to SQL data context and I'm trying to update a field on a record.  The update wasn't working, and a SQL Profiler trace showed that no update command was being issued to the database.  So I narrowed down the exact lines of code and removed various variables to try to simplify.

With the `where` clauses unchanged, what's going on in the debugger right now is as follows:

```
var foo = db.f_pp_Budgets
            .Where(b => b.SeasonKey == seasonID)
            .Where(b => b.Business == businessUnit)
            .Where(b => b.Level == "R")
            .Where(b => b.CodeKey == region.Key)
            .Single().Trade;
// foo is now set to 1
db.f_pp_Budgets
            .Where(b => b.SeasonKey == seasonID)
            .Where(b => b.Business == businessUnit)
            .Where(b => b.Level == "R")
            .Where(b => b.CodeKey == region.Key)
            .Single().Trade = region.Budget.Trade;
// region.Budget.Trade was (and still is) 2
// so the underlying Linq to SQL object should have a 2 in it, right?
var baz = db.f_pp_Budgets
            .Where(b => b.SeasonKey == seasonID)
            .Where(b => b.Business == businessUnit)
            .Where(b => b.Level == "R")
            .Where(b => b.CodeKey == region.Key)
            .Single().Trade;
// baz is set to 1.  Shouldn't it be 2?
```

Since the value is unchanged, calling `db.SubmitChanges()` naturally doesn't send anything to the database.

Can anybody think of a reason why the value wouldn't be changing?

---

**Updated code:** (in response to [@Hogan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9295701/328193))

```
var myObj = db.f_pp_Budgets
              .Where(b => b.SeasonKey == seasonID)
              .Where(b => b.Business == businessUnit)
              .Where(b => b.Level == "R")
              .Where(b => b.CodeKey == region.Key)
              .Single();

var foo = myObj.Trade;
// foo is now set to 1

myObj.Trade = region.Budget.Trade;
// region.Budget.Trade was (and still is) 2

var baz = myObj.Trade;
// baz is now set to 2
```

The object's value is being updated.  However, `db.SubmitChanges()` still doesn't send any `update` statements to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.  It looks like the `System.Data.Linq.Table<>` object was set to `.IsReadOnly = true` because the underlying table had no primary key.  Makes sense, since Linq wouldn't really have a reliable way of tracking the uniqueness of entities if no unique identifier is supplied from the database.

One would hope that the generated code for the entities could make properties on the affected type without setters, or throw an exception on setting.  But there may be other good reasons why that isn't the case, of which I am unaware.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has to do with lvalues as equations.  That is you can't evaluate an expression and then assign to it in c variants.

Simple answer, do this:

```
 var myobj = db.f_pp_Budgets
        .Where(b => b.SeasonKey == seasonID)
        .Where(b => b.Business == businessUnit)
        .Where(b => b.Level == "R")
        .Where(b => b.CodeKey == region.Key)
        .Single();

myobj.Trade = region.Budget.Trade;
```

---

nb to understand why your code did not work, consider the following two illegal assignments:

```
 5+7 = 4
 obj.val + obj2.val = 4
```

Comment: Good explanation, and it's odd that I've never run into that before with Linq to SQL.  However, it appears that the underlying issue I'm having is deeper than that.  I've updated the question to reflect the new code, which is updating the value on `myObj` correctly, but not sending any updates back to the database.

Comment: (Essentially, it appears that my "simplification" of the code introduced the bug you've described, which coincidentally demonstrated the same observed result as the underlying bug.)

Comment: Interestingly enough, after discovering the problem I was having, I set the code back to not use an interim `myObj` and it works fine.  It looks like an assignment can be done in this manner.

Comment: That means it is doing an implied de-reference.  Not that surprised but it is different than C and C++.